# firestore security rules - create new user and check if name is free

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

to create a new user (via email authentication) I have to allow everything in firestore, is there a better way?

```
match /users/{userId=**} {    
    allow get, list;  
    }
```

**Code:**
I check whether the name is already taken

```
  Future<bool> doesNameAlreadyExist(String name) async {
    final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('name', isEqualTo: name)
        .limit(1)
        .get();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;
    return documents.length == 1;
  }
```

authentication then takes place later when the user presses the login button:

```
final auth = Provider.of(context)!.auth!;
        String uid = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          emailController.text,
          passwordController.text,
          nameController.text,
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017880/15774176):

> Enforcing uniqueness is only possible by creating an extra collection.
> In your current structure, to know if a username is unique, you will
> need to read each document. This is incredibly inefficient, and on top
> of that it isn't possible in security rules, since they can only read
> a few documents per rule.

> The trick is to create an extra collection
> of usernames, where you also have a document for each user, but now
> the key/ID of each document is the username. With such a collection,
> you can check for the existence of a certain document, which is a
> primitive operation in the security rules.

For information you can check some similar scenarios - [case_1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238476/15774176) , [case_2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47405774/15774176) and [case_3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51363730/15774176).